# rmcorr package NaN vs. 0 as output

Tags: r, nan, correlation

With rmcorr package, I am getting NaN values when I use the rmcorr_mat. When I use rmcorr function I get NaN but also a warning message

```
Warning message:
In sqrt(SSFactor/(SSFactor + SSresidual)) : NaNs produced
```

Can I replace NaN with 0?
For some I also get a correlation as 0.

Can someone please explain when does rmcorr return a correlation as NaN and 0?

Thanks

```
> =input_file$A001
 [1]  0  0  5  0  0  0  9  3 10 13  0  0 43 38  8  6 38 11 22  7
> input_file$A002
 [1]  0  0  0  0 11 25  0  0  6 11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  6
>rmcorr(participant = factor(subject), measure1 = input_file$A001,measure2 = input_file$A002,CI.level = 0.95,CIs="analytic", dataset = input_file)
Repeated measures correlation

r
NaN

degrees of freedom
9

p-value
1

95% confidence interval
NaN NaN 

Warning message:
In sqrt(SSFactor/(SSFactor + SSresidual)) : NaNs produced

> rmcorr(participant = factor(subject), measure1 = input_file$A003,measure2 = input_file$A004,CI.level = 0.95,CIs="analytic", dataset = input_file)

Repeated measures correlation

r
0

degrees of freedom
9

p-value
1

95% confidence interval
-0.599875 0.599875 

> input_file$A003
 [1] 11  3  2 16  0  0 10  2  0  0  0  0  8 18  0  0  0  0  0  0
> input_file$A004
 [1]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  33 106   0   0   0   0   0  45  48  99   0 151
```